# How to get all elements but div (for example), including nested ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is probably a long shot but is there a way to get a collection of elements in JQuery or not without a specific tag/class/id, even the nested ones?

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```html
<div class="container1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <br><br>
</div>

<p>This is p 1
    <div class="footer">
       tessssst
        <p>
            p test
        </p>
    </div>
</p>

<div class="container">
    tessst
</div>

<p>This is p 2
    <div id="someID" class="container">
        tessssst 2
    </div>
</p>
```

Now, I'm using JQuery like this, in order to find all but div tags, including descendants:

```
$('body').find(':not(div, div *)')
```

In the result collection, I still get the div inside the p elements and I don't want that.
Is there any way to achieve that? I know that this div is part of h1 and since I just want to select elements and not removing or doing DOM manipulations it could be a weird thing to wish for but this is what I need.

The bigger problem - I need to retrieve all text nodes but to exclude some tags/classes/IDs. I'm doing so as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) but it's not good enough.

Thanks.

Comment: You can start writting good semantical code. You should close `h1` after the end of the string and don't append all that don't are part of a heading.

Comment: It's just an example. Imagine that the div is inside a p element. Here, I've changed it to 'p' just for you :)

Comment: Well, I have to say that putting it in h1 got me to this misunderstanding...
After switching from h1 to p, this is working!

Placing the div in the h tag messes up with the selectors I guess.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to work, but maybe you could try this?

```
$('body').find("*").filter(":not(div)");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery function [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), which removes matching elements from the current set.

So all you need to do is

```
var nonDivs = $('body').find('*').not('div');
```

Comment: No, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by first selecting all elements, then selecting `<div>`s and their descendants, and filtering the "all" results with the "divs" result using `.not()` (the red style is used to mark the matched set):

```js
var all = $('body').find('*');
var divAll = $('body').find('div, div *');

var nonDiv = all.not(divAll);

nonDiv.css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <br><br>
</div>

<p>This is p 1
    <div class="footer">
       tessssst
        <p>
            p test
        </p>
    </div>
</p>

<div class="container">
    tessst
</div>

<p>This is p 2
    <div id="someID" class="container">
        tessssst 2
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Wow I really don't understand it. I tried your solution - bottom line it's working.
But I don't understand why.

If I'm trying this piece of code in Chrome: 'var all = $('body').find('*');
var divAll = $('body').find('div, div *');

all.not(divAll);' I get the collection BUT I can still see the div in the collection, same as happened to me and I thought that it doesn't work. If, for example you try '.text()' on this collection you'll still get the text in the div which is not good. I don't need the text in the div.

Comment: But if I do that: '$('body').find(':not(div, div *)').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3})' - then, for some reason it is working, I get only the text that I want. I have no clue why. Do you have any thought?

Comment: What I meant in sort, this is working:
$('body').find(':not(div, div *)').css('color', 'red');
But this will bring all the text, including the ones that are in the nested div(s):
$('body').find(':not(div, div *)').text();
I guess I will open a new question for that.

Comment: @mrgoos - it turns out your original code is fine (`$('body').find(':not(div, div *)')`), so I'm not really getting the problem. What do you mean *I can still see the div in the collection*? can you explain how you're *seeing* it? and what undesirable effect it has? since either using my method, or yours, you can manipulate all non-div nodes, which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

In the filter function check if it's a text node and also check all of its parents for class, id, tag name - whatever selectors you would like to filter by.

```
var textnodes = $('body').find("*").contents()
    .filter(function () {
        return (this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).parents("div").length <= 0);
    })
    .each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hracw15o/3/

Comment: Thanks but for some reason this works too, still don't understand why...
$('body').find(':not(div, div *)').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3});

Comment: Ah yes that does work.  Find() gives you all the nodes except divs, contents() gives you all immediate children of those nodes and filter() only returns text nodes - that's why it works.